# Could not connect to Google cloud SQL. Using PHP Google SDK

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I did read this tutorial 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/
I had created a Instance with name `schoolnbd` and my project id is `myapplication-2013`
After reading the tutorial I tried the code below

```
<?php
$dhost=":/cloudsql/myapplication-2013:schoolnbd";
$duser="root";
$dpassword="xxxyyy";
$database="schoolnbd";
$connection=mysql_connect($dhost, $duser, $dpassword) or die("Could not Connect to SQL Server Suleman");
$db=mysql_select_db($database, $connection) or die(" Check the Database Name from Config.php , wrong database entered ");
?>
```

But it is showing “Could not Connect to SQL Server Suleman”. 
I had created one user by name `suleman` and made several changes , but still it is not connecting to SQL server, i am seeing same message. 
I had tried doing many changes such as

try 1

```
$dhost=":/cloudsql/myapplication-2013:schoolnbd";
$duser="suleman";
```

try 2

```
$dhost="localhost";
$duser="root";
```

try 3

```
$dhost=":/myapplication-2013:schoolnbd";
$duser="root";
```

try 4

```
$dhost=":/cloudsql/myapplication-2013:myapplication-2013:schoolnbd";
$duser="root";
```

try 5

```
$dhost=":/cloudsql/myapplication-2013:myapplication-2013:schoolnbd";
$duser="suleman";
```

Error from the error log is 
`it is Showing mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /base/data/home/apps/s~myapplication-2013/1.371632998623546850/test.php on line 6`

when I am using

```
$dhost=":/cloudsql/myapplication-2013:schoolnbd";
$duser="root";
```

Comment: Can you tell me the what error app engine is showing? You can find the error by clicking `Logs` from your appengine console.

Comment: it is Showing `mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /base/data/home/apps/s~myapplication-2013/1.371632998623546850/test.php on line 6`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i also faced the same problem, try without using password, it like this it will most probably work

```
$dhost=":/cloudsql/myapplication-2013:schoolnbd";
$duser="root";
$dpassword="";
```

but keep in mind , if you had set your root password then you should update root password, by typing this in console.

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root' = PASSWORD('');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are connecting using the root user, from AppEngine, you should not provide a password.