# Encountering timeout error during external network PHP connection to Google Cloud MySQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-storage

I'm attempting a basic PHP connection as root user to a Google Cloud MySQL DB NOT from the App Engine PHP SDK but from a PHP script to be hosted by our current website hosting service.

I'm encountering a timeout error i.e.

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out in
>   ....... on line 8

As I'm already performing CRUD to databases in my instance from Java I'm aware that specific networks are authorised to access a Cloud SQL instance hence I made sure I added the IP address of our website hosting service to the list of authorised networks.

Having read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980298/could-not-connect-to-google-cloud-sql-using-php-google-sdk) although I'm not connecting from the App Engine PHP SDK I'm also aware the how the host value is set is very crucial so could this be where I'm going wrong?

Below is my code:

```
<?php
    // 1.Create a database connection
    define("DB_SERVER", "XXX.XXX.XXX.XX");
    define("DB_USER", "root");
    define("DB_PASS", "password");
    define("DB_NAME", "dbname");

    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

    // Test if connection occured
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "";
        die("DB connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() . "(".mysqli_connect_errno().")");
    } else {
        echo "DB connection worked !!!!";
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Users Log In DB access</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        Content of the document......
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    if(isset($connection)) {
        // 5. Close DB connection
        mysqli_close($connection);
    }
?>
```

Is there a reason I'm encountering the above timeout error? Should I include the port i.e. 3306 in the server string?

Once I can connect from the above code to my Cloud SQL DB then I intend on completing this following [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) with regards to connecting Android to a remote server.

EDIT: Just as a mention I successfully connect to my Google Cloud SQL instance database with MySQL Workbench.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you're using mysql_connect rather than mysqli_connect?

Comment: I tried both mysql_connect and mysqli_connect and I was unsuccessful with both.

Comment: Hi guys... any more ideas?